# phpMyAdmin - Cardinality N,N

Tags: sql, database, data-structures, phpmyadmin

For a project I would need to setup a N,N cardinality but I really do not understand how to setup it in phpMyAdmin, usually work with 1,N cardinality, I've never been that far but I strongly think N,N is the key to my problem.

Here is the situation :

- 1 table manage user
- 1 table manager group of user
- 1 table manage document

Now what I need is :

- N user can access a specific document
- N group can access a specific document

So my problem is how to say in phpMyAdmin, that my document can be link to a unique user OR to a group?
Or maybe I just screw up the structure and that's not what I should do :x

The idea is maybe a group cannot access to a document but a specific user, even inside this same group, could access it. I guess it needs 1 more table to make the link between documents and group/user but I don't see how I should setup it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe you need `ID` in the table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer MAK but I don't get your idea, could you be more clear?

Comment: I think you do not want a UNIQUE user/group to access a document. That means only 1 entity can access the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. I finally found the solution by using a tool I completely didn't know.

[mySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.fr/products/workbench/)

For people also don't know that tool, it helps (a lot!) to develop a database without using phpMyAdmin and with a model viewer. (See screenshot below)

[image]